# what's wrong with this database query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post

Here is a little piece of code in PHP.

```
<?php include_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>
    <?php include_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
    <?php 
        if(!isset($_POST['menu_name']) or !isset($_POST['position']) or !isset($_POST['visible'])){
            echo "You are supposed to fill all entries<br/><br/><a href='new_subject.php'>go back</a>";
            exit;
        }
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($_POST); 
            echo "</pre>":
        $menu_name = $_POST['menu_name'];
        $position = (int)$_POST['position'];
        $visible = $_POST['visible'];
        $menu_name = mysql_real_escape_string($menu_name);
        $subject_count = mysql_num_rows(get_all_subjects());
        //$subject_set_desc = mysql_query("SELECT position FROM subjects ORDER by position DESC",$connection);
        for($change = $position;$change<=$subject_count;$change++){
            //get row with position $change
            //increase it's position by 1
            //continue till all rows end OR loop ends
            /*UPDATE subjects SET position = $change+1 WHERE position = $change*/
            $new_position = $change+1;
            echo "{$change} ".gettype($change)."  {$new_position} ".gettype($new_position)."<br/> ";
            mysql_query("UPDATE subjects SET position = {$new_position} WHERE position = {$change}",$connection);
            echo "UPDATE subjects SET position = {$new_position} WHERE position = {$change}"."<br/>";
            //confirm_query($cheack);
            
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO subjects (menu_name,position,visible) VALUES ('{$menu_name}',{$position},{$visible})";
        if(mysql_query($query,$connection)){
            //header("location:content.php");
            exit;
        } else{
            echo "<b>failed to insert new subject</b> <br/>".mysql_error();
        }
    ?>
    <?php mysql_close($connection); ?>
```

I want you to just focus on the `for` loop and the database query in that loop..
I send following data via `post` to this page

```
$_POST['subject'] = 'new_subject'; //string type <br/>
$_POST['position'] = 1 //int type <br/>
$_POST['visible'] = 1 //tinyint type <br/>
$_POST['submit'] = 'Add Subject' // string type just submisssion <br/>
```

as you can see in my form processing file

[image]

my database before making these queries

[image]

my database after making query (in for loop of code).

[image]

I think position of all the rows in table should increase by 1 but all of them changed to 5..
Here i want to increment position by 1 for those whose position is greater or equal to `$_POST['position']..<br/>`
I try to echo my queries and all of them show that queries are correct but after their execution changes to table are not in way as i though(i want to increment every ones position by 1)..

Comment: Which query is not working INSERT??

Answer (score 1):

You should run it downward; You start with updating position 1 to two. Now there are 2 items with position 2. You then update those to three. Leaving you with three items on position 3.

Rather, start with the highest value, update 4 to 5. Then drop one, increment all the 3 to 4 etc.

Or even better, use one query on all positions that need to increment, without any loops:

```
Update subjects SET position = position +1
```

Comment: thanks buddy i got it... positions are like 1,2,3,4 i m changing 1 to 2 it becames 2,2,3,4 the 2 to 3 it becames 3,3,3,4...

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_position = $change+1;
```

change that line into:

```
$new_position = $position+1;
```

and put it before your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is that you're changing each of the values one at a time.

```
UPDATE subjects SET position = position + 1 WHERE position >= ...
```